# Predicate Logic Natural Number Problems

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I am trying to translate the following statements into predicate logic using the following predicates: $E(x) = x$ is even, $P(x) = x$ is prime, $L(x,y) = x < y$

(i): Some Primes are Odd.

(ii): Every even number is greater than 1.

(iii): There are infinitely many primes.

(iv): The only even prime is 2.

My attempts were

(i): $\neg (\forall x P(x) \implies E(x))$

My reasoning behind this was that saying $\exists x(P(x) \land \neg E(x))$ just says there is at least 1, rather than some odd primes.

(ii): $\forall x E(x) \implies L(1,x)$

(iii): $\forall x \exists y (P(x) \land P(y) \land L(x,y)$

My reasoning for this one was that this means that for every prime, there is a prime that is greater than it, which means there are infinitely many primes.

I am not really sure how to go about (iv)

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: at least one=some, for (iv), The only even prime is 2=all numbers that are prime and not 2 are not even

Comment: The answer for (ii) needs parentheses, to show that $\forall x$ applies to the whole implication, not just to $E(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $ (i) $, both your attempt and the proposition you argue against are actually equivalent, as 
$$\neg (\forall x, P(x) \rightarrow E(x)) \iff \exists x, \neg(P(x) \rightarrow E(x))$$
$$\iff \exists x, \neg( \neg P(x) \vee E(x))$$
$$\iff \exists x, P(x) \wedge \neg E(x)$$

Your attempt for $ (ii) $ is correct.

Your attempt for $ (iii) $ is incorrect, as that is stating that for all $x$, there exists $y$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are prime and that $x$ is less than $y$. But of course, not every natural number is prime, so the statement must be false. What you want is something like

$$ \forall x, \exists y, L(x, y) \wedge P(y) .$$

This loosely says that primes can be arbitrarily large.

$ (iv) $ corresponds to $$ (P(x) \wedge E(x)) \rightarrow (L(1, x) \wedge L(x, 3))$$

if we're given that $ x \in \mathbb{N} $ and only have access to predicates $L, E, P$.

Comment: although the answer is correct I want to give 2 notes: (1) in the first part you used both $\implies$ as part of formula and $\iff$ to show equivalent formalization, this is a bad notation, you should either use $\rightarrow$ and $\iff$ or $\implies$ and $\equiv$ to make thing clearer. (2) usually it is acceptable that we don't write ∃x, A but (∃x)A or ∃xA.(the overall answer is great +1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful!